# TestRestTemplate - Log response without destroying the body

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

In order to log the request and response I have added a **LoggingRequestInterceptor** which implements **ClientHttpRequestInterceptor**...

The response body is a stream and if I read it my interceptor it won’t be available for TestRestTemplate to deserialize it into my object model. In other words, when I call testRestTemplate.get… I’ll always get back empty objects (even as I see the object my response).

To solve this for RestTemplate it can be fixed by using a **BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory**. I don't know how to fix it for TestRestTemplate though...

I have tried to add BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory to an instance of RestTemplate and then wrap TestRestTemplate with that instance:

```
restTemplateBuilder.configure(restTemplate);
```

...but then there's no logging at all.

This is how I add the logging interceptor.

```
public static RestTemplateBuilder withInterceptors() {
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        interceptors.add(new LoggingRequestInterceptor());

        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .interceptors(interceptors);
    }
```

In the end I would like to:
1. Log the response body
2. Deserialize it into a object model (now it's null if I turn on logging)

Answer (score 1):

```
TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

testRestTemplate.getRestTemplate()
                .setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));
```

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way to debug request/response is by setting this in the properties:

```
logging.level.org.apache.http=DEBUG
```

And with BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper:

```
public class LoggingRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingRequestInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(final HttpRequest request, final byte[] body,
            final ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);

        response = log(request, body, response);

        return response;
    }

    private ClientHttpResponse log(final HttpRequest request, final byte[] body, final ClientHttpResponse response) {
        final ClientHttpResponse responseCopy = new BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper(response);
        logger.debug("Method: ", request.getMethod().toString());
        logger.debug("URI: ", , request.getURI().toString());
        logger.debug("Request Body: " + new String(body));
        logger.debug("Response body: " + IOUtils.toString(responseCopy.getBody()));
        return responseCopy;
    }

}
```

and setting up:

```
LoggingRequestInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new LoggingRequestInterceptor();
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(loggingInterceptor);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also found another way. See below: